# PGFplot histogram using multiple barplots

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I'am trying to create a colored histogram using barplots using the following code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar,
ymin=0,
bar width=0.2cm,
axis x line*=left,
nodes near coords=\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
enlarge x limits=false,
grid=major,
height=7cm,
title={All Results},
xlabel={bias from reference in \%},
ylabel={Number of Results},
symbolic x coords={$<-20$,$-20$,$-19$,$-18$,$-17$,$-16$,$-15$,$-14$,$-13$,$-12$,$-11$,$-10$,$-9$,$-8$,$-7$,$-6$,$-5$,$-4$,$-3$,$-2$,$-1$,$0$,$1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6$,$7$,$8$,$9$,$10$,$11$,$12$,$13$,$14$,$15$,$16$,$17$,$18$,$19$,$20$,$>20$},
xtick=data,
xticklabel style={inner sep=0pt, anchor=north east, rotate=45},
width=\textwidth]
\addplot[red,fill=red!40!white] coordinates {($<-20$,3) ($-20$,2) ($20$,0) ($>20$,0)};
\addplot[yellow,fill=yellow!40!white] coordinates {($-19$,1) ($-18$,2) ($-17$,0) ($-16$,1) ($-15$,0) ($15$,0) ($16$,0) ($17$,0) ($18$,0) ($19$,0)};
\addplot[blue,fill=blue!40!white] coordinates {($-14$,0) ($-13$,1) ($-12$,1) ($-11$,0) ($-10$,1) ($10$,0) ($11$,1) ($12$,0) ($13$,0) ($14$,1)};
\addplot[green,fill=green!40!white] coordinates {($-9$,1) ($-8$,5) ($-7$,14) ($-6$,46) ($-5$,105) ($-4$,185) ($-3$,126) ($-2$,297) ($-1$,276) ($0$,301) ($1$,250) ($2$,153) ($3$,67) ($4$,85) ($5$,37) ($6$,29) ($7$,9) ($8$,2) ($9$,10)};
\legend{Bad,Fair,Good,Excellent}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Resulting in something that almost looks great, but I'am missing some x tick and some bars are not on the right spot :(

Someone got an idea to fix this, or can suggest an alternative?

Grtz,
  Berry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one problem in your listing: if you say `ybar` as axis option, `pgfplots` prepares the overal axis for one or more bar plots - and *groups* these bars automatically.

This grouping causes your problem "are not on the right spot" (please refer to the reference manual to see the use case for this grouping).

Thus, the main solution is to avoid `ybar` as axis option. If you write `/tikz/ybar`, it will work. In this case, the axis is unaware of bar-specific stuff and you can proceed as usual. You may want to add `ybar legend` (to format the legend as for bar plots) and `xtick align=outside` explicitly.

The other question "where are my remaining tick labels!?" can be solved by stating which tick positions should be displayed - your choice of `xtick=data` displays the x coordinates *of the first plot*. In your case, that is `$<-20$,$-20$,$20$,$>20$`. A solution would be to provide a "more useful" selection.

Here is a suggestion which has a selection of ticks and two "extra xticks" for the boundaries:

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[/tikz/ybar, % -------- CF
ybar legend, %-------- CF
xtick align=outside,% -------- CF
ymin=0,
bar width=0.2cm,
axis x line*=left,
nodes near coords=\rotatebox{90}{\scriptsize\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta},
enlarge x limits=false,
grid=major,
height=7cm,
title={All Results},
xlabel={bias from reference in \%},
ylabel={Number of Results},
symbolic x coords={$<-20$,$-20$,$-19$,$-18$,$-17$,$-16$,$-15$,$-14$,$-13$,$-12$,$-11$,$-10$,$-9$,$-8$,$-7$,$-6$,$-5$,$-4$,$-3$,$-2$,$-1$,$0$,$1$,$2$,$3$,$4$,$5$,$6$,$7$,$8$,$9$,$10$,$11$,$12$,$13$,$14$,$15$,$16$,$17$,$18$,$19$,$20$,$>20$},
xtick={$-20$,$-15$,$-10$,$-5$,$0$,$5$,$10$,$15$,$20$},
minor x tick num=4, % ----------- CF
extra x ticks={$<-20$,$>20$},% ----------- CF
extra x tick style={xticklabel style={yshift=-15pt}},% ----------- CF
%xticklabel style={inner sep=0pt, anchor=north east, rotate=45},% ----------- CF
width=\textwidth]
\addplot[red,fill=red!40!white] coordinates {($<-20$,3) ($-20$,2) ($20$,0) ($>20$,0)};
\addplot[yellow,fill=yellow!40!white] coordinates {($-19$,1) ($-18$,2) ($-17$,0) ($-16$,1) ($-15$,0) ($15$,0) ($16$,0) ($17$,0) ($18$,0) ($19$,0)};
\addplot[blue,fill=blue!40!white] coordinates {($-14$,0) ($-13$,1) ($-12$,1) ($-11$,0) ($-10$,1) ($10$,0) ($11$,1) ($12$,0) ($13$,0) ($14$,1)};
\addplot[green,fill=green!40!white] coordinates {($-9$,1) ($-8$,5) ($-7$,14) ($-6$,46) ($-5$,105) ($-4$,185) ($-3$,126) ($-2$,297) ($-1$,276) ($0$,301) ($1$,250) ($2$,153) ($3$,67) ($4$,85) ($5$,37) ($6$,29) ($7$,9) ($8$,2) ($9$,10)};
\legend{Bad,Fair,Good,Excellent}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

You may want to give a little bit extra space using, say, `enlarge x limits=0.01`