# Two histograms with curve on top, using precomputed data (tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How do I recreate something similar to the matlab figure (screenshot below)?

My data is extremely numerous so I am unable to write a txt file for tikz to read in and make its own histogram. Therefore, both the boxes and the curve are precomputed and the data is organised like so:

**data1.txt** columns:

1. box centre x value (could be changed to edges/ranges?)
2. red box height
3. blue box height

**data1.txt**:

```
0.016667,0.00022427,0.00080371
0.05,0.00071525,0.0040343
0.083333,0.0046128,0.010322
0.11667,0.013802,0.032195
0.15,0.036641,0.12487
0.18333,0.081648,0.27605
0.21667,0.16501,0.46263
0.25,0.3536,0.74299
0.28333,0.79652,1.1873
0.31667,1.8911,2.0495
0.35,4.4014,4.1998
0.38333,7.5493,7.3397
0.41667,6.3889,5.708
0.45,3.2463,2.9518
0.48333,1.6616,1.5891
0.51667,0.97415,0.94628
0.55,0.62952,0.62525
0.58333,0.44008,0.43485
0.61667,0.31792,0.30966
0.65,0.23995,0.2274
0.68333,0.18397,0.17262
0.71667,0.1425,0.13699
0.75,0.11246,0.11085
0.78333,0.09094,0.089117
0.81667,0.074713,0.070143
0.85,0.061524,0.059001
0.88333,0.050546,0.048995
0.91667,0.042927,0.041824
0.95,0.035841,0.03634
0.98333,0.023197,0.023922
```

**data2.txt** columns:

1. curve x points
2. curve y points

**data2.txt**

```
0.2,0.50939
0.22105,0.75941
0.24211,1.0842
0.26316,1.4822
0.28421,1.9405
0.30526,2.4329
0.32632,2.921
0.34737,3.3584
0.36842,3.6977
0.38947,3.8987
0.41053,3.9365
0.43158,3.8062
0.45263,3.5243
0.47368,3.125
0.49474,2.6536
0.51579,2.1577
0.53684,1.6802
0.55789,1.2529
0.57895,0.89472
0.6,0.61185
```

Preferably, I'd like to avoid  `pgfplotstableread` as I like to keep the reference to the data file right in the tikzpicture.

*On the other hand, perhaps there is a different way to do the figure?* The histograms need to be close because the differences are quite small.

For reference, I've been puzzling over [how-can-already-binned-data-be-plotted-as-a-histogram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194852/how-can-already-binned-data-be-plotted-as-a-histogram), [histogram-with-overlaying-gauss-curve-pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237085/histogram-with-overlaying-gauss-curve-pgfplots), and [plot-histogram-and-add-already-fitted-density-function](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211461/plot-histogram-and-add-already-fitted-density-function).

[image: matlab output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps I don't understand the question correctly. Is it something like this what you want?

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data2.txt}
0.2,0.50939
0.22105,0.75941
0.24211,1.0842
0.26316,1.4822
0.28421,1.9405
0.30526,2.4329
0.32632,2.921
0.34737,3.3584
0.36842,3.6977
0.38947,3.8987
0.41053,3.9365
0.43158,3.8062
0.45263,3.5243
0.47368,3.125
0.49474,2.6536
0.51579,2.1577
0.53684,1.6802
0.55789,1.2529
0.57895,0.89472
0.6,0.61185
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{data1.txt}
0.016667,0.00022427,0.00080371
0.05,0.00071525,0.0040343
0.083333,0.0046128,0.010322
0.11667,0.013802,0.032195
0.15,0.036641,0.12487
0.18333,0.081648,0.27605
0.21667,0.16501,0.46263
0.25,0.3536,0.74299
0.28333,0.79652,1.1873
0.31667,1.8911,2.0495
0.35,4.4014,4.1998
0.38333,7.5493,7.3397
0.41667,6.3889,5.708
0.45,3.2463,2.9518
0.48333,1.6616,1.5891
0.51667,0.97415,0.94628
0.55,0.62952,0.62525
0.58333,0.44008,0.43485
0.61667,0.31792,0.30966
0.65,0.23995,0.2274
0.68333,0.18397,0.17262
0.71667,0.1425,0.13699
0.75,0.11246,0.11085
0.78333,0.09094,0.089117
0.81667,0.074713,0.070143
0.85,0.061524,0.059001
0.88333,0.050546,0.048995
0.91667,0.042927,0.041824
0.95,0.035841,0.03634
0.98333,0.023197,0.023922
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  width=\textwidth,
  title={The title},
  ymin=0,
  xmin=0,
  xmax=1,
  ymax=8
]
\addplot[ybar,bar width=10pt,fill=red!60,opacity=0.8] 
  table[col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=1] {data1.txt};
\addplot[ybar,bar width=6pt,fill=blue!80,opacity=0.6] 
  table[col sep=comma,x index=0,y index=2] {data1.txt};
\addplot[no marks,line width=1pt] 
  table[col sep=comma] {data2.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```