# tikz: how to shade (with lines) areas in a histrogram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I have the following code that works beautifully.

```
% Source: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65518/5645
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{penciline}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width=+\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance,
    auto corner on length=1mm,]{
        \pgfpathcurveto%
        {% From
            \pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}
                      {\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
        }
        {%  Control 1
        \pgfmathrand
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{0pt}
        }
                    {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect
                     \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}%
                               {\pgfmathresult\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
                    }
        }
        {%TO 
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}{\pgfpoint{1pt}{1pt}}
        }
    }
    \state{final}{}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=penciline, decorate]
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar interval,
            xticklabel=
            \pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick
        ]
            \addplot+[hist={bins=3}]
            table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 6\\
            7\\ 6\\ 9\\ 8\\ 5\\ 2\\
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

What I want to do is to have the bars in the histogram shaded (not colored) with lines at an angle of 45 degrees, say). How do i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to get some 45 degree lines and the like is to use `patterns.meta`. Yet this does not really support decorations. So, assuming that you want to have decorated lines, you can use a `path picture`. (Notice that one can generalize this to allow for arbitrary slope angles, if needed.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{penciline}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width=+\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance,
    auto corner on length=1mm,]{
        \pgfpathcurveto%
        {% From
            \pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}
                      {\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
        }
        {%  Control 1
        \pgfmathrand
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{0pt}
        }
                    {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect
                     \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}%
                               {\pgfmathresult\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
                    }
        }
        {%TO 
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}{\pgfpoint{1pt}{1pt}}
        }
    }
    \state{final}{}
}
\tikzset{manual pattern/.style={manual pattern keys/.cd,#1,
    /tikz/path picture={
    \path
    let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north east)-(path picture bounding box.south west)$),
    \n1={scalar(int(1+(\x1+\y1)/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/manual pattern keys/distance}))}
    in foreach \z in {0,...,\n1}
    {($(path picture bounding box.south west)+(0,-\x1+\z*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/manual pattern keys/distance})$)
     edge[/tikz/manual pattern keys/lines] ++ (\x1,{\x1})
    };
}},manual pattern keys/.cd,distance/.initial=5pt,
    lines/.style={draw}}
\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=penciline, decorate]
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar interval,
            xticklabel=
            \pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick
        ]
            \addplot+[hist={bins=3},fill=none,
                postaction={manual
                pattern={lines/.style={decorate,decoration=random steps}}}]
            table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 6\\
            7\\ 6\\ 9\\ 8\\ 5\\ 2\\
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}

\begin{preview}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=penciline, decorate]
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar interval,
            xticklabel=
            \pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick
        ]
            \addplot+[hist={bins=3},fill=none,
                postaction={manual
                pattern={lines/.style={decorate}}}]
            table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 6\\
            7\\ 6\\ 9\\ 8\\ 5\\ 2\\
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The upper picture is just to show that it really works, the second one uses the peniciline from your code but one has to look a bit more carefully to see that the lines are a bit irregular.

This is a version that works with newer versions of `pgfplots` and allows you to set the distance and angle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{penciline}{initial}{
    \state{initial}[width=+\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance,
    auto corner on length=1mm,]{
        \pgfpathcurveto%
        {% From
            \pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}
                      {\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
        }
        {%  Control 1
        \pgfmathrand
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}{0pt}
        }
                    {\pgfqpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentaspect
                     \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance}%
                               {\pgfmathresult\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
                    }
        }
        {%TO 
        \pgfpointadd{\pgfpointdecoratedinputsegmentlast}{\pgfpoint{1pt}{1pt}}
        }
    }
    \state{final}{}
}
\tikzset{manual pattern/.style={manual pattern keys/.cd,#1,
    /tikz/path picture={
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mybeta}{Mod(270+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/manual pattern keys/angle},180)-90}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\myt}{\mybeta<-45?0:(\mybeta<0?1:(\mybeta<45?2:3))}
    \def\myxshift{0pt}
    \def\myyshift{0pt}
    \ifcase\myt
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydelta}{abs(cos(\mybeta))}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\myd}{1/abs(sin(\mybeta))}
     \def\mystart{path picture bounding box.north west}
     \def\myxshift{-\y1*\mydelta+\z*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/manual pattern keys/distance}*\myd}
    \or 
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydelta}{abs(sin(\mybeta))}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\myd}{1/abs(cos(\mybeta))}
     \def\mystart{path picture bounding box.north west}
     \def\myyshift{\x1*\mydelta-\z*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/manual pattern keys/distance}*\myd}
    \or 
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydelta}{abs(sin(\mybeta))}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\myd}{1/abs(cos(\mybeta))}
     \def\mystart{path picture bounding box.south west}
     \def\myyshift{-\x1*\mydelta+\z*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/manual pattern keys/distance}*\myd}
    \or 
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\mydelta}{abs(cos(\mybeta))}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\myd}{1/abs(sin(\mybeta))}
     \def\mystart{path picture bounding box.south west}
     \def\myxshift{-\y1*\mydelta+\z*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/manual pattern keys/distance}*\myd}
    \fi
    \path
    let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north east)-(path picture bounding box.south west)$),
    \n1={scalar(int(1+(\x1+\y1)/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/manual pattern keys/distance}))},
    \n2={max(\x1,\y1)*sqrt(2)}
    in foreach \z in {0,...,\n1}
    {([xshift=\myxshift,yshift=\myyshift]\mystart)
     edge[/tikz/manual pattern keys/lines] ++ (\mybeta:\n2)
    };
}},manual pattern keys/.cd,distance/.initial=5pt,angle/.initial=45,
    lines/.style={draw}}
\begin{document}

\begin{preview}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=penciline, decorate]
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar interval,
            xticklabel=
            \pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick
        ]
            \addplot+[hist={bins=3},fill=none,
                postaction={manual pattern={angle=30,lines/.style={decorate}}}]
            table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 6\\
            7\\ 6\\ 9\\ 8\\ 5\\ 2\\
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}

\begin{preview}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decoration=penciline, decorate]
        \begin{axis}[
            ybar interval,
            xticklabel=
            \pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick
        ]
            \addplot+[hist={bins=3},fill=none,
                postaction={manual pattern={angle=-30,distance=3pt,
                    lines/.style={decorate}}}]
            table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
            data\\
            1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 6\\
            7\\ 6\\ 9\\ 8\\ 5\\ 2\\
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This does the work. How do I change the angle? Also, what if I want to decrease/increase the density of the lines?

Comment: the initial = 1pt increases the lines per shading.

Comment: However, there is a warning: Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable tick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} into your preamble on input line 40.

Comment: @user3236841 I added a second, more flexible version that cooperates with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`.

Comment: One more question: is it possible to remove (a) the vertical lines in the graph, (b) the axis at the top and the right side?

Comment: @user3236841 Add `axis lines=left,major grid style={draw=none},` to the options of the axis.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! One more question, when I do the above, I get the top bar a little erased.

Comment: @user3236841 Yes, but this is almost a "coincidence". The problem is that the decorated lines are a bit irregular, and overshooting parts get clipped away. Luckily the fix is as simple as adding `clip=false,` to the options of the axis. (I assume that if you have a boxed axis, the bounding box is slightly larger.)

Comment: Thanks again! This works. Btw, what does the begin, end preview do?

Comment: @user3236841 I don't really know, I just copied them from your code. I usually use the standalone class for such things, e.g. `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}`, then I do not have to use begin, end preview.

Comment: I see:-) thanks!